# How to show utf-8 decoded value in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, utf-8

Requirement:
To decode data of utf8  **K& #2446;Ler** which is possible by v-html attribute in vuejs

Problem:
Don't know how to pass displayFullUserName to data-tooltip which holds value **Armin K& #2446;Ler** so that it will reflect **Armin Koler** in grey layout.

Finding
The below image shows gibberish data K& #2446;Ler, since it is not rendered by v-html.
I have a data-tooltip property which shown below as **grey** over tooltip view.
Now, I don't know how to fix this as actual text rendered above was by v-html tag.

[image]

```
 <label
   v-bind:data-tooltip="displayFullUserName"
   v-html="displayFullUserName"
 />

computed() {
return this.displayFullUserName;
}
```

Comment: one way is like `htmlEntity2utf8(s) { const t= document.createElement('span'); t.innerHTML = s; return t.textContent }` not sure if there's a more modern way to do this common conversion

Comment: The proper solution would be to not have it HTML encoded in the first place.

Comment: I am getting from api, can't help @gre_gor

Comment: And `K& #2446;Ler` doesn't produce "Köler". It should be `K&#246;ler`.

Comment: @Bravo thanks your solution works. put your solution in answer

Comment: @gre_gor thanks for effort, we ned to put in inter html, really appreciate your efforts

Answer (score -1):

It worked with below solution

```
htmlEntity2utf8(s) { 
 const t= document.createElement('span'); t.innerHTML = s; 
 return t.textContent 
}
```

thanks @Bravo for this.

Comment: This executes JavaScript. `htmlEntity2utf8('<img src="dummy" onerror="alert(\'xss\')">')`

Comment: @gre_gor - huh? where does `<img src="dummy" onerror="alert(\'xss\')">` come from? nothing to do with the OPs code!

Comment: @Bravo It doesn't matter where it comes from. The function is insecure and there are better solutions.

Comment: @gre_gor "better solutions" ... a) post one of these better solutions, just one, and b) since the original code does `v-html="displayFullUserName"` then the insecurity exists already anyway - surely the `displayUserName` is already sanitised

Comment: @Bravo a) It's in the duplicate target I posted. b) I wouldn't trust it and the function might not be only used in this specific case. Also Q&A on this site need to be useful for future readers which probably won't have sanitized input.

Comment: @gre_gor - sorry, didn't see the duplicate you posted - my bad - and yes, that is far superior

Comment: @gre_gor - even better because it can be a one liner - `const htmlDecode = input => new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html").documentElement.textContent;`